# Mysql - Daily Sum by currency

Tags: mysql

```
select DATE(added), SUM(amount) ,currency 
from transactions 
where  DATE(added)  > subdate(CURDATE(),10) 
AND status = 'APPROVED' GROUP BY  DATE(added);
```

This will return one sum per day which is wrong since i  have many currencies.
i want to get daily sum's by currency. 
example:

```
24/10/2019 EUR 15000
24/10/2019 USD 18000

23/10/2019 EUR 55000
23/10/2019 USD 68000
```

Comment: And? what is the question?

Comment: How i will get the results like this 
24/10/2019 EUR 15000
24/10/2019 USD 18000

23/10/2019 EUR 55000
23/10/2019 USD 68000

the above query will return :
24/10/2019 USD 18000
23/10/2019 USD 18000
It will sum up all currencies

Comment: Adjust your group by according to your wishes.. - group by date will only deliver 1 set of data for the whole day ... you want probably group by currency, DATE(added) - untested though

Comment: what about you [clarify](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) your question?

Comment: He's probably assuming his result example is enough clarification - And for me it was

Answer (score 0):

... adding to my recent comment ...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e8f57/4

```
select DATE(added), SUM(amount) ,currency 
from transactions 
where  DATE(added)  > subdate(CURDATE(),10) 
  AND status = 'APPROVED' 
GROUP BY  currency,DATE(added)
ORDER BY DATE(added) desc;
```

delivers daily amounts separated by currency as you wanted